# Capistrano: Checkout files from two different repository

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I have two repositories in BitBucket.

One is my normal repository which I would like to deploy with first, a Laravel installation, I would like to deploy all the files within the branch.

My problem is, there is another repository that contains a single file, that would like to checkout to a directory in the server. That file is a class that I don't use locally but is essential for server.

I have no idea how to approach this.

Here is my deploy.rb file:

```
#config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.6.1'
#require custom config
require './config/myconfig.rb'

set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"

set :application, '<Application Name>'
set :repo_url, '<Url to my First main repo>'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'

set :user, 'vagrant'
```

Here is my staging.rb file:

```
set :deploy_to, '<Directory to deploy to>'

server '<Server name or IP>', user: 'vagrant', roles: %w{app db web}

namespace :deploy do

    desc 'Get stuff ready prior to symlinking'
    task :compile_assets do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
       execute "cp #{deploy_to}/../components/.env #{release_path}"
       execute "cp -r #{deploy_to}/../components/vendor #{release_path}"
       execute "cp -r #{deploy_to}/../components/node_modules #{release_path}"
       execute "cd #{release_path}; gulp;"
    end
  end
  after :updated, :compile_assets
end
```

How do I bring in that single file (app/Extentions/TaskOneExtention.php in Repo 2) and put it in a directory (say app/Extentions in Repo 1)?

I would like the task to run after deploy task but run with the same deploy command.

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done in this case is use two Capistrano deployments and some symlinks.

For the sake of this answer, let's define `$REPO1HOME` as the location to which Repo1 is deployed.

First, I would add the filename in Repo2 as a shared_file in Repo1 (config/deploy.rb):

```
set :shared_files, 'app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php'
```

At this point, when you deploy Repo1, a symlink will be created from `$REPO1HOME/releases/[timestamp]/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php` to `$REPO1HOME/shared/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php`. Of course this latter file doesn't exist yet, and the deploy will fail.

To make this file exist, deploy Repo2 to the server. Let's presume it is now in `$REPO1HOME/repo2/` and the file in question is now in `$REPO1HOME/repo2/releases/[timestamp]/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php`. Create a symlink in `$REPO1HOME/shared/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php` which points to `$REPO1HOME/repo2/current/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php`. Make sure that this is an absolute symlink and not a relative one.

```
ln -s $REPO1HOME/repo2/current/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php $REPO1HOME/shared/app/Extensions/TaskOneExtension.php
```

At this point, you should have two repositories which can be independently deployed, and then linked up on the server.